# Can anybody detect file in directory www (nginx)?

Tags: nginx

ubuntu 16.04 x64. I install nginx, do not change default configuration.

I have `/var/www/html` with one index file. I see content of index file, if open my site in browser.

Now I copy new file to /var/www/html (place near index). Ofcouse I know file name and can append to site url this name and open file in browser.

Can anybody detect this file and open it in browser too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different tools that can scan your website using a list (or lists) of popular files/folders. If you want to keep these files private but still accessible to someone, you can:

1. Name them unusually (you can simply use a hash of the file as the filename, that would take years to guess the name)
2. Restrict access to files/folders using HTTP authentication.
3. Place them outside of your root folder (e.g. in `/var/www/private/`) and write a simple page that will read the file (you can still add auth and everything, e.g. IP whitelisting) in your favorite language (Ruby, PHP, NodeJS, Python, Go, etc.)

I'd go with the second one. See [the nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html) to learn how to configure it.

Comment: I think OP was asking if one could scan the server for available files, so as to not have to guess

Comment: @android-dev you are right

Comment: Thus there is no longer any point to this answer, Defman please use the `delete` button on your post to delete it unless you can [edit] it to answer the question properly.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is very unsecured to left data only *behind* `index.html`.
A lot of tools is designed to search this files.
Named for this tools are `URL fuzzer`. You have online version [here](https://pentest-tools.com/website-vulnerability-scanning/discover-hidden-directories-and-files).

> The URL Fuzzer uses a custom built wordlist for discovering hidden
>   files and  directories. The wordlist contains more than 1000 common
>   names of known  files and directories. For each WORD in the wordlist,
>   it will make an HTTP  request to: Base_URL/WORD/ or to
>   Base_URL/WORD.EXT in case you chose to fuzz  a certain EXTension.

Edit 1

Meybe "behind" is not best expression. You can create additional folder in `DokumentRoot` folder on you site and protect them with `.htaccess`. Configuration of `.htaccess` you can find [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04). You will get folder with username/passwork protection.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your 'behind'. And whats's the secure way?

Comment: You have my Edit 1 in answer.

Comment: [nginx does not recommend using .htaccess](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/).

More over, nginx does not support them.

Comment: No it doesn't. The only way to get htaccess working with nginx is the nginx+apache stack which is an overkill in the OPs situation.